# Scala java.lang.NoSuchElementException Error

Tags: scala, for-loop, apache-spark, nosuchelementexception

I have a Scala for loop that goes like this:

```
val a = sc.textFile("path to file containing 8 elements")
for(i <- 0 to a.count.toInt)
{
    println((a.take(i).last))
}
```

But it throws java.lang.NoSuchElementException error.
I am not able to understand what's wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: Which line throws?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to print all the elements in the file one by one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: println((a.take(i).last)) throws the error

Comment: Can you not just iterate directly over `a`? For example, `for (i <- a) println(i)`.

Comment: all you need is `a.foreach(println)` - don't try iterating over RDDs, it defies the whole purpose of Spark - you're fetching the data from the cluster into your driver application instead of sending your _functions_ (like `println` in this case) _to_ the cluster, which is how Spark is designed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems

1) The "to" operator for defining range (in 0 to a.count.toInt) is a problem here as it is inclusive range from 0 to 8. In a collection of 8 elements, it is trying to access element at index 8.

You can use 0 **until** a.count.toInt.

2) Second problem is the way "last" operator is called. When i=0, the expression a.take(i) is an empty collection and hence calling "last" on it results in NoSuchElementException.

Why would you iteratively take 1, 2, 3...8 elements from a collection just to take the last element everytime?

It is ok to do what you are doing with a collection of 8 elements but if you wanted to do this on a larger RDD, you should consider caching the RDD if you want to do something like this on a larger RDD.

Comment: I checked and the second problem you mentioned actually throws the error.

Comment: Yes, right calling "take" with a larger argument doesn't cause any issues.